# break onclick event from method

Tags: c#, events, break

Button's `OnClick` event is called:

```
private void vkb7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //method
    button_start(object sender);

    // do stuff 2
}
```

Some method is triggered:

```
private void button_start(object sender)
{
    bool some = true;
    if (some)
    {
        return; // I'd also like to break "button click"
    }
}
```

I'd like to break "button click" event from method - how do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean "break" button click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, let `button_start()` return a boolean:

```
private bool button_start(object sender)
{
   bool some = ...;
   return some;
}


private void vkb7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //method
  if (button_start(object sender))
    return;

  // do stuff 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are determining in `button_start` whether actions should occur in `vkb7_Click_1`, consider making `button_start` return `bool` and then use the return value in `vkb7_Click_1`.

On the other hand, if you are encountering an error condition in `button_start`, [throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "block" the event as it has already been fired. You can however handle the click manually depending on the result.

```
private void vkb7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool result = button_start(sender);

    if (result)
        DoSomething();
    else
        DoSomethingElse();
}

private bool button_start(object sender)
{
    bool some = true;

    if (some)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, Set the return type of `button_start` to `bool`
 
**Second**, If you want to pass sender of `vkb7` button or properties of `vkb7` button,

 Then you should pass it like this:

> button_start(sender)
>   So the code would be like this:

```
 private void vkb7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //method
   if(button_start(sender))
   // do stuff 2
 }
```

Then in the method

```
 private bool button_start(object sender)
 {
    bool some = true;
    if (some)
    {
       return true; // I'd also like to break "button click"
    }
    else  
    return false;
 }
```